# PostgreSQL: Exception when relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql

Here I am trying to display a error message when relation does not exist then exception occurred.

**Example**:

```
Create or replace function fun_test() returns void as
$$ 
Begin
     Truncate testtb;
     Exception 
     When does_not_exist then /* When testtb does not exist*/
          raise info 'Relation does not exists';
     ...
```

**ERROR**:  unrecognized exception condition "does_not_exist"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition "does_not_exist" does not exist.
Refer to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html

For testing use code like this ...

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '%; SQLSTATE: %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
```

If you want to truncate more tables I suggest to use a function.

Answer (score 6):

You can handle with "undefined_table".

```
EXCEPTION WHEN undefined_table THEN
     RAISE NOTICE '%; SQLSTATE: %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
```